# How to get row index of matching row in table using EF 5?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a Customers table having various fields, one of them is "PostCode"
I want to find order the customers by customername, and want to find the index of a first row matching the Postcode

For example, It should return me index of first customer having postcode "WS01 3GE" after ordering them by customer name.
I have no idea of how to achieve it.

Could anyone please help me out this?

Thanks

Comment: do you have any idea of LINQ. If yes, you can achive it easily in LINQ.

Comment: Yes, I have fair idea of LINQ. Can you guide me how?

Comment: See answer by @Dennis Traub below. That what I was talking about!

Comment: No, using "ToList" will make the performance suffering in case if there are few lacs of rows.

Comment: What about `Takewhile` in Linq.

Answer (score 0):

Not very efficient because it loads the whole table, but you can start with this and optimize as needed.

```
int index = yourContext.Customers
                       .OrderBy(x => x.CustomerName)
                       .ToList();
                       .FindIndex(x => x.PostCode == "WS01 3GE");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this new solution,

```
var Customers = yourContext.Customers.OrderBy(x => x.CustomerName);
int counter=0;
foreach (Customer customer in Customers)
{      
  if(customer.PostCode == "WS01 3GE")
    break;
    counter++;
}    //index will be in counter variable
```

I have n't tried but should work

Comment: No, this gives me error saying "System.NotSupportedException"

Comment: ok, I didn't try it on my m/c, but now I realise that `TakeWhile` is not supported in LINQ to Entities Queries. as per MSDN, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx

Comment: yes, any other alternate... or will I need to loop through :(